# React library wont let to set default value to 100

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, arrays

I'm using React allotment, as you can see i have set defaultSizes={[0, 100]}, it means right side should take whole width and left side should be 0 (default sizes), but as you can see from image below that part should not be shown by default, any idea how to make it really 0 ?

[image]

code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-rgb-k8vdv0?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "./styles.css";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ background: "blue", minHeight: "42px" }}>Monitor</div>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "100%", background: "darkblue" }}>
        <div
          style={{
            border: "1px solid orange",
            width: "100px",
            height: "100%",
            background: "gray"
          }}
        >
          side content
        </div>
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              background: "red",
              border: "3px solid yellow"
            }}
          >
            <Allotment defaultSizes={[0, 100]}>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
          </div>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: any idea is appreciated !

Comment: you want to be able to still "open" the left side from 0? otherwise it would not make sense to use allotment, right?

Comment: @Dean i want it to work as it is working right now, but in default right side should be 100% and left side 0, so user can open it if he wants to by normally pulling

Comment: if i check into the github, you can see the minimum size is 30px https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment scroll down to defaultSizes and you should see it

Comment: there should be some way ?

Comment: it seems the width is internally handled at all times. so even setting it over the inspect window to 0px does not work (because i assume it is automatically reset to 30px).

Comment: @Dean i found a way to solve it, we need to set defaultSize to 0 and also minSize to 0

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this and thought i should write an answer so incase if somebody needs to solve same problem,
i needed to add minSize also to it in order to work
defaultSizes={[0, 100]} minSize={0}

code:

```js
              <Allotment defaultSizes={[0, 100]} minSize={0}>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./the-mandalorian.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
              <Allotment.Pane>
                <div style={{ height: "40px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    height: "100%",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    justifyContent: "space-between"
                  }}
                >
                  <div>
                    <img
                      style={{ width: "100%", height: "auto" }}
                      src={require("./nature.jpg")}
                      alt="cat"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ height: "20px", background: "brown" }}></div>
                </div>
              </Allotment.Pane>
            </Allotment>
```